# Looking for algorithms

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

I have a problem I'm trying to solve and I'm looking for an algorithm to solve it. I'm sure a solution exists I just don't know what it's called to search for it.

If I describe the nature of the problem and the desired results, and ask for an approach / algorithm, is that an appropriate question for this site?

Comment: Seems legit.  See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/1204